# Initiate proactive prompt without breaking dialog in bot framework

Tags: bots, botframework, chatbot

Hi I have a proactive quiz bot where I send a message every few hours and people get a chance to participate in the quiz. There are 2 ways to begin a dialog in node.js using the bot framework if I am not mistaken

```
bot.send()
bot.beginDialog()
```

The 1st one doesnt end the current dialog while the second one does. I want to give the user a question like What is 1500 + 450 and 4 choices 1800 1950 2500 3000 and start the dialog only if the person answers the question above. How can I do it without breaking the current dialog stack?

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is basically not possible - Using proactive messages does not enable you to change the current context's call stack - It only enables you sending messages to the user.

The only way I would think about bypassing this is using [middleware](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.middleware) to intercept messages and decide if you should change the callstack or not (using beginDialog).

This is also not optimal since you might have the following scenario:
1. Current call stack question: "How many years of experience do you have?"
2. Proactive prompt: "Choose an answer: 1) 1000. 2) 2000 etc.."

If the user types "2" which context is he referring to?

Maybe a good solution would be to ask the user to type "quiz answer: 2" which will enable you to intercept this message using middleware:

```
bot.use({
    botbuilder: function (session, next) {
        if (/^(quiz answer)/g.test(session.message.text)) {
            session.beginDialog('/quizAnswer');
        }
        else {
            next();
        }
    }
});
```

After the dialog */quizAnswer* ends, it will return to the normal flow.
Keep in mind, that even in that case - the user might not remember which context he was in, and you'll have a hard time trying to figure out what was the last message/prompt etc...

Maybe a better solution would be to have a separate bot for the quiz.

Comment: Ok quick question I came across this issue that addresses something similar I guess https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1352 but I havent figured out how beginDialogAction is supposed to fix this, any ideas?

Comment: I haven't tries this, but if I'm not mistaken, this works a lot like middleware - meaning, no matter what state are you in, if a certain work is received by the bot, start a new dialog. Just like endConversationAction picks out works like cancel/quit which will always clear the current stack.